# While reading itself till delimiter count matches using python

Tags: python

Input is sequence file and line is not end with newline, while reading complete file is taking into one line and file size is 22GB . Is it possible to read till delimiter count matches. Please suggest me am new to python.
I tried with f.read()
Line = count(;)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that the community can provide you with the best assistance.

Comment: My input file is sequence file and there is no new line so while reading file entire 22gb file into one line

Answer (score 0):

In the `f.read()` function you can add an option like `f.read(5)` so that, it will read 5 caracters. So you can do something like:

```
delimiter = ";"
output = ""
while True:
    c = f.read(1):
    if not c:
        break;
    if delimiter in c:
        break;
    output = output+c
```

Obviously, you can choose all delimiter you need.

Comment: sorry, I did a mistake. `c = f.read(1)` without the ':' at the end